# retrieve a count of child values under the parent values in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, where-clause

one work order can have many child work orders.
i need to check if that parent_WO has any child_wo
if yes need to display
parent WO no, number of child WOs ,pm_no

[image: Table values and Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select parent_wo, count(*) child_wo_count, pm_no
from mytable
where parent_wo <> child_wo_no
group by parent_wo, pm_no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use case expression:

```
select parent_wo, pm_no,
sum(case when parent_wo <> child_wo then 1 end) as total
from table1 group by parent_wo, pm_no;
```